# How can I access git files on a heroku CI dyno?

Tags: git, heroku, continuous-integration

The `.git` folder does not seem to be present on Heroku CI Dynos

I can attach to the dyno as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci#debugging

```sh
$ heroku ci:debug --pipeline
Preparing source... done
Creating test run... done
Running setup and attaching to test dyno...

~ $ pwd
/app

~ $ cd .git
bash: cd: .git: No such file or directory
```

But I want to run tooling that requires the .git folder to be present to compare shas and files.

More info on Heroku CI: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-technical-detail-on-ci-lifecycle